# Uncaught Error: Class "Symfony\Bundle\DebugBundle\DebugBundle" not found

Tags: php, symfony

I trying to deploy my application (Symfony 6 and php 8) through the Gandi.net french service. When I run the command to deploy the app by ssh I get the following error message in my terminal :
Executing script cache:clear [KO]
[KO]
Script cache:clear returned with error code 255
!!  Symfony\Component\ErrorHandler\Error\ClassNotFoundError {#75
!!    #message: """
!!      Attempted to load class "DebugBundle" from namespace "Symfony\Bundle\DebugBundle".\n
!!      Did you forget a "use" statement for another namespace?
!!      """
!!    #code: 0
!!    #file: "./vendor/symfony/framework-bundle/Kernel/MicroKernelTrait.php"
!!    #line: 131
!!    trace: {
!!      ./vendor/symfony/framework-bundle/Kernel/MicroKernelTrait.php:131 { …}
!!      ./vendor/symfony/http-kernel/Kernel.php:382 { …}
!!      ./vendor/symfony/http-kernel/Kernel.php:768 { …}
!!      ./vendor/symfony/http-kernel/Kernel.php:128 { …}
!!      ./vendor/symfony/framework-bundle/Console/Application.php:166 { …}
!!      ./vendor/symfony/framework-bundle/Console/Application.php:72 { …}
!!      ./vendor/symfony/console/Application.php:171 { …}
!!      ./vendor/symfony/runtime/Runner/Symfony/ConsoleApplicationRunner.php:54 { …}
!!      ./vendor/autoload_runtime.php:29 { …}
!!      ./bin/console:11 {
!!        › 
!!        › require_once dirname(**DIR**).'/vendor/autoload_runtime.php';
!!        › 
!!        arguments: {
!!          "/tmp/build.14jKbmPhHD/vendor/autoload_runtime.php"
!!        } 
!!      }
!!    }
!!  }
!!  2022-03-11T15:10:40+00:00 [critical] Uncaught Error: Class "Symfony\Bundle\DebugBundle\DebugBundle" not found
!!
Script @auto-scripts was called via post-install-cmd
-----> Building new application failed
-----> Aborting deployment

This is the 2 files where the DebugBundle is mentioned.

- Composer.lock

  "autoload": {
  "psr-4": {
  "Symfony\Bundle\DebugBundle\": ""
  },
  "exclude-from-classmap": [
  "/Tests/"
  ]
  },
- Bundles.php

  ['all' => true],
            Doctrine\Bundle\DoctrineBundle\DoctrineBundle::class => ['all' => true],
            Doctrine\Bundle\MigrationsBundle\DoctrineMigrationsBundle::class => ['all' => true],
            Symfony\Bundle\DebugBundle\DebugBundle::class => ['dev' => true], 
            Symfony\Bundle\TwigBundle\TwigBundle::class => ['all' => true], 
            Symfony\Bundle\WebProfilerBundle\WebProfilerBundle::class => ['dev' => true, 'test' => true],
            Symfony\WebpackEncoreBundle\WebpackEncoreBundle::class => ['all' => true],
            Twig\Extra\TwigExtraBundle\TwigExtraBundle::class => ['all' => true],
            Symfony\Bundle\SecurityBundle\SecurityBundle::class => ['all' => true],
            Symfony\Bundle\MonologBundle\MonologBundle::class => ['all' => true],
            Symfony\Bundle\MakerBundle\MakerBundle::class => ['dev' => true],
            Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\SensioFrameworkExtraBundle::class => ['all' => true],  
        ];

The error suppose that I forgot a “use” but I never instantiate the DebugBundle so I never had to write a use for him. 
I try to run composer require symfony/debug-bundle and do a composer update but nothing change.
 
I already try to change de content of the composer.lock by changing :

```
"autoload": {
                "psr-4": {  
                    "Symfony\\Bundle\\DebugBundle\\": ""   
                }, 
                "exclude-from-classmap": [  
                    "/Tests/" 
                ]  
            },
```

To

```
"autoload": {  
                "psr-4": {  
                    "Symfony\\Bundle\\DebugBundle\\": “App\src”   
                },
                "exclude-from-classmap": [  
                    "/Tests/"   
                ] 
            },
```

but when the composer install or update is run the “App/src” is delete and the file return to is original value.
I’m running out of idea so I hope your guys can help me.

Have a nice day.

Aimerick

[terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4re1H.png)
[Bundles.php](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mZ8a6.png)
[composer.lock](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pxmsA.png)

Comment: I guess problem is  your composer file. it should be like that "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "src/"
        }
    }

Answer (score 2):

I'm getting the same error, what I think is happening is that the composer command is installing the "prod" requirements, meaning it will correctly skip those bundles mentioned in "require-dev" as those are development only.

However, there must be some code in the runtime that isn't checking on which env it's running on or a misconfiguration that still tries to load *all* bundles when the Kernel is loading, (or it's not aware of the APP_ENV=prod), and therefor *still* tries to load the debug bundle (and other dev bundles), even though these were not installed by composer.

You'll notice these are the bundles that have dev => true in bundles.php.
You'll notice that by removing these one by one, the error will shift to the next one that has dev => true.

I have made sure my env vars are set before any composer command is run, so it can't be that.

When SHH'ed into my server, I can go into the "bin" directory of my project and run "php console about" there. It seems to think it's a dev env, even though its deployment script ought to have set the APP_ENV var.

#php console about

---

Symfony

---

Version              6.0.8
Long-Term Support    No
End of maintenance   01/2023 (in +269 days)
End of life          01/2023 (in +269 days)

---

Kernel

---

Type                 App\Kernel
Environment          dev
Debug                true
Charset              UTF-8
Cache directory      ./var/cache/dev (1.7 MiB)
Build directory      ./var/cache/dev (1.7 MiB)
Log directory        ./var/log (0 B)

---

PHP

---

Version              8.1.5
Architecture         64 bits
Intl locale          en_US_POSIX
Timezone             Europe/Brussels (2022-05-07T16:18:34+02:00)
OPcache              true
APCu                 true
Xdebug               false

---

So what I assume is that the "export APP_ENV=prod" and "export APP_DEBUG=0" are not remembered by the system.

Therefor, I ran "composer dump-env prod" manually on the system, and that generates a .env.local.php containing the APP_ENV and APP_DEBUG lines, and now these are respected and the site seems to load (onwards to fixing my data).

Comment: So the first step towards the solution would be to find out what the values of `APP_ENV` and `APP_DEBUG` are, and whether these contain any values at all, just before they get passed to `new Kernel(...)`.

Answer (score 0):

read this [article](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/30782), it works for me with symfony 6

**context:**

symfony/profiler-pack and his dependencies "twig\Bundle" are loaded
"require-dev": { "symfony/profiler-pack": "^1.0" }
And could not be installed on context "prod"

**solution:**

If you want to use "Twig\Bundle" in other context you sould load separately with:
`composer require symfony/twig-bundle`.
Now TwigBundle is in "require" and symfony/profiler-pack in "require-dev"