# I can't deploy Symfony demo app to Google App Engine

Tags: symfony, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

I have taken all the steps to create the Symfony Demo App and then deploy it to Google App Engine. Locally the App works, but when I try to deploy it to Google executing `gcloud app deploy` it throws the following error:

```
File upload done.
Updating service [default]...failed.                                                                  
ERROR: (gcloud.app.deploy) Error Response: [9] Cloud build 8c83ab19-e20d-4d11-9ec0-734a47b3e80c status: FAILURE
...ress the notice in phar:///layers/google.php.composer-install/composer/bin/composer/vendor/symfony/finder/Iterator/ExcludeDirectoryFilterIterator.php:71
Deprecation Notice: Return type of Symfony\Component\Finder\Iterator\ExcludeDirectoryFilterIterator::getChildren() should either be compatible with RecursiveIterator::getChildren(): ?RecursiveIterator, or the #[\ReturnTypeWillChange] attribute should be used to temporarily suppress the notice in phar:///layers/google.php.composer-install/composer/bin/composer/vendor/symfony/finder/Iterator/ExcludeDirectoryFilterIterator.php:76
Deprecation Notice: Return type of Symfony\Component\Finder\Iterator\FilterIterator::rewind() should either be compatible with Iterator::rewind(): void, or the #[\ReturnTypeWillChange] attribute should be used to temporarily suppress the notice in phar:///layers/google.php.composer-install/composer/bin/composer/vendor/symfony/finder/Iterator/FilterIterator.php:30
Deprecation Notice: Return type of Symfony\Component\Finder\Iterator\PathFilterIterator::accept() should either be compatible with FilterIterator::accept(): bool, or the #[\ReturnTypeWillChange] attribute should be used to temporarily suppress the notice in phar:///layers/google.php.composer-install/composer/bin/composer/vendor/symfony/finder/Iterator/PathFilterIterator.php:27
80 packages you are using are looking for funding.
Use the `composer fund` command to find out more!

Run composer recipes at any time to see the status of your Symfony recipes.

Executing script cache:clear [KO]
 [KO]
Script cache:clear returned with error code 255
!!  Symfony\Component\ErrorHandler\Error\ClassNotFoundError {#70
!!    #message: """
!!      Attempted to load class "DebugBundle" from namespace "Symfony\Bundle\DebugBundle".\n
!!      Did you forget a "use" statement for another namespace?
!!      """
!!    #code: 0
!!    #file: "./vendor/symfony/framework-bundle/Kernel/MicroKernelTrait.php"
!!    #line: 135
!!    trace: {
!!      ./vendor/symfony/framework-bundle/Kernel/MicroKernelTrait.php:135 { …}
!!      ./vendor/symfony/http-kernel/Kernel.php:382 { …}
!!      ./vendor/symfony/http-kernel/Kernel.php:766 { …}
!!      ./vendor/symfony/http-kernel/Kernel.php:128 { …}
!!      ./vendor/symfony/framework-bundle/Console/Application.php:166 { …}
!!      ./vendor/symfony/framework-bundle/Console/Application.php:72 { …}
!!      ./vendor/symfony/console/Application.php:171 { …}
!!      ./vendor/symfony/runtime/Runner/Symfony/ConsoleApplicationRunner.php:54 { …}
!!      ./vendor/autoload_runtime.php:29 { …}
!!      ./bin/console:11 {
!!        › 
!!        › require_once dirname(__DIR__).'/vendor/autoload_runtime.php';
!!        › 
!!        arguments: {
!!          "/workspace/vendor/autoload_runtime.php"
!!        }
!!      }
!!    }
!!  }
!!  2022-11-01T03:03:46+00:00 [critical] Uncaught Error: Class "Symfony\Bundle\DebugBundle\DebugBundle" not found
!!
```

I have the file `app.yaml` in the root folder of the project with this content:

```
runtime: php81
# threadsafe: true

handlers:
# tell appengine where our static assets live
- url: /bundles
  static_dir: web/bundles

# the symfony front controller
- url: /.*
  script: web/app.php

# [START env_vars]
env_variables:
  SYMFONY_ENV: prod
# [END env_vars]
```

### My environment

- Mac OSX M1 (Apple Silicon)
- PHP 8.1.12
- Symfony CLI version 5.4.17
- Composer version 2.4.4
- Google Cloud SDK 406.0.0

Any help to solve this problem?

Comment: `SYMFONY_ENV` was [discontinued with Symfony Flex (4.0+)](https://symfony.com/doc/5.4/deployment.html#c-install-update-your-vendors) it should be `APP_ENV: prod`.

Comment: @WillB. I simplified the `app.yaml` content according to [this](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/php-gen2/config/appref?hl=es-419) and it's working fine.

Comment: Not following what you mean, as that page only provides the syntax specifications and examples for gCloud `app.yaml` file, where I said you used the wrong variable name for determining the Symfony environment in that file under the `env_variables` section.

Answer (score 0):

I've solved it by running this in the console:

```
composer dump-env prod
```

This has generated a file `.env.local.php` with this content:

```
<?php

// This file was generated by running "composer dump-env prod"

return array (
  'APP_ENV' => 'prod',
  'APP_SECRET' => 'THESECRET',
  'DATABASE_URL' => 'sqlite:///%kernel.project_dir%/data/database.sqlite',
);
```

and the application has been deployed without error.

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72153316/5587982).

Comment: Generally speaking, `.env.local`, where you typically supply sensitive app details like `APP_ENV`, is not deployed to the production server, which causes `.env` to be read which defines `APP_ENV=dev`. You're expected to define `APP_ENV` as a environment variable or  run `composer dump-env prod` is the [recommended approach](https://symfony.com/doc/current/deployment.html#b-configure-your-environment-variables) for performance optimization.